# WebSphere: incompatible with javax.resource.spi.ResourceAdapter

Tags: websphere, classcastexception, websphere-8

We are trying to deploy an `.ear` in WAS8.5 Application Server. During the application startup an error is thrown of incompatible `ResourceAdapter`. The complete stack trace is here. 
What could be the possible cause of this? Any pointer would be of great help. Thanks in Advance.

```
J2CA0043E: An Exception occurred while trying to instantiate a ResourceAdapterJavaBean instance for the installed ResourceAdapter defined by key cells/ux9039Cell01/applications/globalmc-mq-ear.ear/deployments/globalmc-mq-ear/deployment.xml#J2CResourceAdapter_1423058973553.

The exception is: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.gdc.ps.frd.globalmc.ra.NextRecordResourceAdapterImpl incompatible with javax.resource.spi.ResourceAdapter**
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RAWrapperImpl.createAndConfigureRA(RAWrapperImpl.java:2236)
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RAWrapperImpl.startRA(RAWrapperImpl.java:712)
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RALifeCycleManagerImpl.startRA(RALifeCycleManagerImpl.java:1170)
...

FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDCIncident emitted on /apps/WAS8.5/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/FFMNode/logs/ffdc/FFMUxSrvr_87506fa8_15.02.05_04.29.59.6196455942349878479476.txt com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RALifeCycleManagerImpl.startRA 1324
[2/5/15 4:29:59:700 CST] 0000007e RALifeCycleMa E   J2CA0128E: An Exception occurred while trying to start ResourceAdapter cells/ux9039Cell01/applications/globalmc-mq-ear.ear/deployments/globalmc-mq-ear/deployment.xml#J2CResourceAdapter_1423058973553. T**he exception is: java.lang.ClassCastException:** com.gdc.ps.frd.globalmc.ra.NextRecordResourceAdapterImpl incompatible with javax.resource.spi.ResourceAdapter
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RAWrapperImpl.createAndConfigureRA(RAWrapperImpl.java:2236)
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RAWrapperImpl.startRA(RAWrapperImpl.java:712)
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RALifeCycleManagerImpl.startRA(RALifeCycleManagerImpl.java:1170)
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RALifeCycleManagerImpl.resourceProviderEvent(RALifeCycleManagerImpl.java:884)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that com.gdc.ps.frd.globalmc.ra.NextRecordResourceAdapterImpl is not a javax.resource.spi.ResourceAdapter.

Has something in your configuration asserted that this class represents a JCA Resource Adapter? It would appear that it isn't.

Comment: yes, it implements javax.resource.spi.ResourceAdapter. Also the jar (thinclient.jar) which has the ResourceAdapter class is in the sharedlib location used by app in WAS. Does WAS has to do something with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have multiple copies of class javax.resource.spi.ResourceAdapter. Basically, multiple jars has the same class which is causing the issue.

Comment: Right, even I thought the same at the start, but when I did a extensive search in all the libraries(accesed via WAS shared lib) used by application. There is only one jar with this class. Would this be a conflict from WAS? if so, is there a setting in WAS to get rid of the conflict?

Comment: You should look not just in shared lib. Look into within your war/ear .  Look into server lib too!!

Comment: the .ear also has no conflicting class. And yes, my suspect is also with WAS server, but can the WAS libs be touched?
If so wouldn't it affect other application? or is there a way to do it?